# Why is the static keyword used in UITableViewCell identifiers?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've read up on "static" on several occasions, including just before posting this question.
I'm still searching for an "Aha" though.

In the context of UITableView's static comes up in Cell Identifiers in every piece of code I've looked at. For example in a recent CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    static NSString *defaultIndentifier = @"Managed Object Cell Identifier";
```

My question is why do we need and use "static"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So that it will only be constructed once. If it's not static, you'll be making one every time the message is sent (which is a lot)

Comment: If by "making one every time" you mean "pushing a constant pointer into a stack variable", sure. But it's just as expensive as saying `int i = 3;`, as the compiler has compiled `@"Identifier"` into a constant. The only time the static would actually be a benefit is if the string is constructed at runtime instead of using a constant string.

Comment: That's still a benefit. It cuts out two processor cycles every time the method is run (which could be a lot of times).

Comment: @ughoavgfhw yeah, but doesn't it make your binary bigger and make your app use more memory?

Comment: @Matt It may or may not make the binary bigger, depending on the initial value, type, etc. Remember, it has to come from somewhere whether it is static or not. It is very unlikely to make your app take more memory because the variable is the same size, just in a different place.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw whether a variable is static or automatic may not change its size in memory, but static variables exist for the entire lifetime of the app whereas can't an automatic variable be overwritten after the method returns? Then, won't your app be able to use less memory when not processing that method? The compiler allocates space in the binary for static variables but not for automatic variables, correct? So, won't using a static variable likely increase the binary size?

Comment: @Matt If you are writing a value to a variable, that value has to either in the binary or calculated from things in the binary, no matter what type of variable it is. Yes, automatic variables get freed, but then they need to be recreated next time. The big picture depends on a lot of details, so if you want to discuss it more, we can go to chat. In the end, it really doesn't matter because the app will not be given memory a few bytes at a time, so it is unlikely to actually make a difference.

Answer (score 20):

There's no real benefit here. It's mostly just a hint to the reader that the same value is used for all cells in this particular bit of code. As the identifier itself is a constant string, it gets compiled into an immutable chunk of memory and referenced as the same pointer every time, e.g. there is no cost involved in constructing the string even if you remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: Good insight on "the identifier itself is a constant string"

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that by declaring the string as static, that every time it gets passed into `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierforIndexPath:` that the same pointer is used each time (as statically declared variables are allocated only once on the heap, very early in a program's execution)

`[NSString -isEqualToString:]` is most likely implemented to perform a pointer compare first, followed by a character-wise compare as the fallback, which I supposed could shave off a few cycles on each iteration.

There's not much to gain from this, as (a) table cell re-population operates on a typically very small set of cells, and is well optimized, and (b) table refresh is bursty -- it happens once and then doesn't happen again until the user scrolls or application logic changes up the content -- if you end up calling `-reloadTable` 100 times a second, then there's clearly something wrong with your application logic.

I suspect the static keyword is a vestigial legacy convention -- maybe back in the day, Apple hashed on the pointer, rather than performing a proper string compare.